# Redirect from index page in Spring and Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, redirect

I have a Spring application, which is running on Tomcat say at: http://example.com/foo/

DisplatcherServlet is mapped to app/*, for example, index page is:

```
http://example.com/foo/app/index.html
```

This is so because I have other servlets (for HttpRequestHandlers), e.g. mapped to service/*. This scheme is convenient to use because this way app/ and service/ can have different security settings.

What I want is http://example.com/foo to redirect to http://example.com/foo/app/index.html.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your web.xml, you can define a welcome file, seen when navigating to the root of the app:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

You can then make a tiny index.jsp that redirects to where you want:

```
<% response.sendRedirect("app/index.html"); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the [(tuckey) Url Rewrite Filter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to your application.

It provides you the functionality to define URL rewrite rules in you Application (ingoing and outgoing).

So you can define a rewrite rule for `\` that it rewrites to `myApplication.startpage` - or something else.

@see: http://mattgivney.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-url-rewrite-in-spring-mvc.html - for a short example