# Spring Security - url rewriting

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using a `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` with `useForward=true` and `loginFormUrl="/login.jsp"` and hence the login url of my application is - `http://sub.domain.com`

Upon successful login I redirect to `http://sub.domain.com/app`. Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet is mapped to all `/app/*` requests.

My questions are:

1. On logout, I am redirecting the user
   to `login.jsp`, the url in the browser
   changes to
   `http://sub.domain.com/login.jsp` but
   I want the url to be
   `http://sub.domain.com` as was with
   the first login. How can I achieve
   this?
2. Once logged in, if the user
   tries to access -
   `http://sub.domain.com`, it results in
   a 404 error. How can I redirect the
   user to `http://sub.domain.com/app`
   whenever the request for
   `http://sub.domain.com` comes in.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, send a redirect to the root of your application during logout

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST} )
    public void logout(HttpServletResponse response) {

        //Do the real logout, clear session.

        try {
            response.sendRedirect("/");
            } catch (IOException e) {
               //handle the exception
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**For 1)** specify the `logout-success-url` within the spring security `<logout>` element.

@see Chapter B.1.13 The  Element of [Spring Security Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html)

**For 2)** specify a default target url (for successful login)

```
 default-target-url="/app" 
 always-use-default-target="true"
```

@see Chapter B.1.5 The   Element of [Spring Security Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html)

or for a general solution, @see Stackoverflow Question: [Redirect from index page in Spring and Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727642/redirect-from-index-page-in-spring-and-tomcat)

Comment: For the answer to my first question, the logout does work, but what I want is an address bar url of http://sub.domain.com after logout and not http://sub.domain.com/login.jsp. For the second answer, the default-target-url is for specifying the url the user should be redirected to right after he logs in. What I want is to redirect an authenticated user to that url (http://sub.domain.com/app) when he enters the url - http://sub.domain.com (as long as the authenticated Principal is available in the session).

Comment: @Joji: for the second: "What I want is to redirect an authenticated user to that url (sub.domain.com/app) when he enters the url - sub.domain.com  (as long as the authenticated Principal is available in the session)" - redirect ALL users to this url, and protect that it is only aviable for loged in users.