# Redirect the main page to a subpage

Tags: html, linux, redirect, ubuntu-16.04, tomcat8

I have problem. I have own application server where running Ubuntu 16.04 and Tomcat8. When I write name of the page to the browser I want redirect <strike>connect</strike> the main page to the subpage. For example, when I write `www.example.com` I want subpage `www.example.com/home` returned to client.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean “connected”? Redirected?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Redirected

Comment: Maybe related: [Tomcat base URL redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1363605/608639), [Redirect from index page in Spring and Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5727642/608639), [Redirect All the Pages in Home Page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24055314/608639) and several others.